# How to add buttons in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to add two buttons in edit page. I have default scaffold generated. I have tried to add a button in the _form.html.erb file in this way: <%= f.submit 'accept'%> and <%= f.submit 'reject'%> but because this form is rendered in new.html.erb so the buttons are also appearing in new page. I want these buttons only in edit page. I am new to ruby and rails. can any one please help. thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the contents of _form.html.erb to both the edit and new files. Replacing the template call to _form. Then edit the contents of each file separately to suit your needs. After you copy the contents of _form over to the new and edit view files you can delete the _form file.

Comment: @AB but it not follow the DRY

Answer (score 0):

you should check the action name to show your second button like

```
<% if controller.action_name = 'edit' %> 
   <%= f.submit 'reject'%>
<% end %>
```